# This Program Hangs_networking

Tags: java

*Note-I have tried to make my pc both server and client.*

I tried a lot but cannot understand the reason my program hangs.

Whenever i click connect,program hangs.

**Client Side**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
 class chatboxClient {
 JFrame fr;
 JPanel p;
 JButton send;
 JTextArea ta;
 JRadioButton rb;
 chatboxServer cbS=new chatboxServer();

 chatboxClient() {

 fr=new JFrame("ChatBox_CLIENT");
 p=new JPanel();
 send=new JButton("send");
 send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {       // action listener for send
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    sendActionPerformed(ae);
  }
 });
 ta=new JTextArea();
 ta.setRows(20);
 ta.setColumns(20);
 rb=new JRadioButton("Connect");               // action listener for connect
 rb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  connectActionPerformed(ae); 
  }
 });
 fr.add(p);
 p.add(ta);
 p.add(rb);
 p.add(send);
 fr.setSize(500,500);
 fr.setResizable(false);
 fr.setVisible(true);
}

 public void connectActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  try {
   cbS.Laccept();
   rb.setEnabled(false);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame()," Sockets InterConnected!");
  } catch(Exception exc) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame()," Connection Error..");
  }
  }

 public void sendActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
   try { 
String s=ta.getText();
InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket(3000,address);
byte buffer[]=new byte[800];
buffer=s.getBytes();
DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length,address,3000);
if(true) {
     ds.send(dp);

     cbS.Receive(s); // call Receive method of chatboxServer class
    }
 }  catch(Exception exc) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Error sending Message");
  }
```

}

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  new chatboxClient();
 }
}
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class chatboxServer {
 JFrame fr;
 JPanel p;
 JTextArea ta;
 JButton send;
 ServerSocket ss;
 byte buffer[]=new byte[800];

chatboxServer() {
fr=new JFrame("ChatBox_SERVER");
p=new JPanel();
ta=new JTextArea();
ta.setRows(20);
ta.setColumns(20);
send=new JButton("send");
fr.add(p);
p.add(ta);
p.add(send);
fr.setVisible(true);
fr.setSize(500,500);
fr.setResizable(false);
```

}

```
public void Receive(String sm) {
 try {
 buffer=sm.getBytes();
 InetAddress address=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
 DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket(3000,address);
 DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
 ds.receive(dp);
 String s=new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());
 ta.setText(s);  
}  catch(Exception exc) {
    System.out.println("Error Receiving..");
   }
```

}

```
  public void Laccept() {
    try {
      ss=new ServerSocket(3000);     // First making port number 3000 on server to listen
      Socket s=ss.accept();
    } catch(Exception exc) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Accept Failed :3000 :Server Side");
      }  
  }
 }
```

The part that i think is causing a  problem is when i call to `Laccept()`.

The output:
[image]

[image]

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program waits for a connection on TCP port 3000 in `Laccept`. 
Since this is called in `actionPerformed` it blocks the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). This is the Thread responsible for managing GUI events and updating the screen. When the EDT is blocked, the GUI will be blocked - frames will not be updated, no reaction on input, ... the application hangs!
You must run such code in another Thread to avoid blocking the EDT: see [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Nowhere in the posted code a TCP connection to port 3000 is being opened!
Seams like you are mixing TCP (Socket, ServerSocket) and UDP (DatagramSocket).
See [Networking Basics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/overview/networking.html), [All About Sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) and [All About Datagrams](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html) as a start.

EDIT:
Basic idea:

```
// run outside the EDT
thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        Laccept();
    } 
}); 
thread.start();
```

Obs: `invokeLater` is used to force the code to run in the EDT. The documentation says:

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed asynchronously on the AWT event dispatching thread.

Comment: @ Carlos Heuberger It still is not working...I tried this in main method `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
          new chatboxClient();
         }
        });`

Comment: @Suhail - this is no help since `Laccept` is not being executed in another Thread as it is still being called directly in `actionPerformed`! `actionPerformed` is always run in the EDT (when called by the GUI. Have you tried the tutorials I recommended above??

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: I'm impressed!! I updated my answer adding a sample.

Comment: @ Carlos Heuberger I have not successfull so far. I have tried this `try {
    r=new Runnable() {
      public void run() { 
       cbS.Laccept();
        
      }
    };
  } catch(Exception exc){}
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);`

Comment: @ Carlos Heuberger the above try does also hangs the program.Please suggest a way out

Comment: @Suhail Gupta - why don't you do as I suggested (`new Thread(...`)? As long as you use `invokeLater` you will block the GUI!

Comment: @ Carlos Heuberger it is not working:(     Just to make sure,i want to tell you that i am running that snippet just after `new chatboxClient()`(in the main method).If this is an error,then please help.

Comment: @ Carlos Heuberger yes! The program does not hang anymore.I have used a worker thread to solve the problem.But connection is not being made.I think `Socket s=ss.accept();` (this statement) is creating a problem.

Comment: I repeat: "Seams like you are mixing TCP (Socket, ServerSocket) and UDP (DatagramSocket)." As far as I know, it's not possible to connect a `DatagramSocket` to a `Socket` or a `ServerSocket`.

Comment: @  Carlos Heuberger It could be,but now the program waits at `Socket s=ss.accept();`.Is there any problem with it ?

Comment: @  Carlos Heuberger Can you suggest how else i can send and receive messages?

Comment: @Suhail Gupta - that is another *question*... but I would use (only) TCP and do almost the same as in the "All About Sockets"

Comment: @  Carlos Heuberger I have revised the above code and posted the [new problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566867/nothing-happens-when-i-click-connect).If you will run that code,you will actually be able to send messages (just click send twice!!??).But now the problem is that i am able to send message before connecting!! How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are waiting for ever for a packet. I suggest you log when you send a packet and when you reciever it. Or you use a debugger to do the same.

UDP is a lossy protocol, unless your receiever is listening when the packet is sent, it will be lost (it can be lost anyway due to any number of reasons)

Comment: I have fixed some typos, thank you. Is there something specific you wanted me to add?

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey  i cannot understand  your answer.

Comment: I don't know what you don't understand unless you give me a hint. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey "You are waiting for ever for a packet".How am i waiting?

Comment: `ds.receive(dp);` as the Javadoc states `This method blocks until a datagram is received. `

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey Can you suggest a solution

Comment: Open the DatagramSocket as early as possible to minmise the chance of missing  packet. Only wait for a packet in a background thread. Write your problem to allow for lost packets.  If you can't do the last piece, you need to use TCP i.e. Sockets instead.

Comment: I explained why it makes a difference. What is your doubt?  Using UDP reliably is an advanced programming technique. I would suggest you should know how to do this with TCP Sockets before attempting to use UDP.